# Relationship between compiling in x86/x64 and MSIL

Tags: compilation, x86, 64-bit, jit, cil

So I know that if you compile for Any CPU, you get an MSIL output. If you compile as x86, you get an x86 output.

My understanding of the process is like as follows

```
.NET Code -> Compiler -> MSIL -> JIT compiled in CLR -> Native Instruction
```

My question is if you compile in x86/x64, does that skip the `MSIL -> JIT compiled in CLR` step above? Or is my understanding off?

Comment: For a managed assembly, the CPU flavour only restrict the interpreter used. Now there are four flavor: anyCPU (run anywhere, use OS bitness), anyCPU-32bitpreferred (run anywhere there is 32-bit and use 32-bit), x64 (require a 64-bit x86 OS), x86 (require a 32-bit x86 OS). Unless you deal with unmanaged DLLs, this options is of little use.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is not quite correct. Providing the assembly consists of only managed code, it will *always* be compiled to pure MSIL, regardless of the compiler setting (AnyCPU/x86/x64), so even if you compile as x86, you still get MSIL.

If you compile as AnyCPU, then your assembly can run as or be loaded into a 32 bit or 64 bit process, whereas if it's compiled as x86, it can only run as (or be loaded into) a 32 bit process. Similarly, when compiled as x64, it can only run as (or be loaded into) a 64 bit process. The same MSIL is used in either case, and the JIT compiles the MSIL to the required 32/64 bit native code.

Comment: Is it really "the same" MSIL, or did you mean that it's just still MSIL either way?  I don't use .NET or Windows, but I'd assume that targeting x86-only or x64-only would do optimizations in the MSIL that are only valid for 32-bit pointers, or only valid for 64-bit pointers, or things like that.  So maybe the JIT-compiler has less work to do if the ahead-of-time compiler has already started to specialize?

Comment: @PeterCordes a quick test suggests that the only differences between the output when compiling a project as AnyCPU/x86/x64 are a few headers indicating the compilation type - the actual MSIL generated was identical, leaving all the platform-specific optimizations to the JIT.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for checking on that.  I wonder what the point is, then.  Ah, [What does the Visual Studio "Any CPU" target mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/516730) suggests that unmanaged code might do things that depend on bitness.

Comment: In a previous question I had, when I used dotPeek to view the exe produced by Any CPU compilation, dotPeek had an MSIL label for it. When x86 compiled the label would say x86. I think my confusion was because of that MSIL label. Maybe MSIL for JetBrains just means it can be loaded into 32/64 bit processes, and not that it's literally MSIL (it is but the 32 bit exe was as well)